# What will be a very elegant way to raise an error in Python

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, raise, raiserror

I am currently writing a banking application, and below you can see my code:

```
from customer import Customer
from exceptions import KeyError

class Bank(object):
    """ All the bank operations are contained in this class e.g customer Registration """

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = str(name)
        self.customers = dict()
        self.registration_customer(name)

    def registration_customer(self, name):
        """ Registration of a new user to the bank
        Args:
            name (str): name of the customer
        """
        name = str(name)
        if not self.customers.get(name, None):
            self.customers[name] = Customer(name)

    def close_customer_account(self, name, account_type):
        """ close an account of a customer by name and account_type
        Args:
            name (str) : name of the account holder
            account_type (str) : type of account
        """
        name = str(name)
        account_type = str(account_type)
        customer = self.customers.get(name, None)
        if customer:
            customer.close_account(account_type)

    def get_customer_info(self, name):
        """ get customer info
        Args:
            name (str) : name of the customer
        """

        if not self.customers[name]:
            raise KeyError('I am sorry! Customer does not exist')

        return self.customers[name]
```

**Raising an error**

If you see `get_customer_info` function, if the `name` is not present, then I am raising an `error`. Is this the best way I can raise an `error` in Python assuming banking application are super critical ? You can also assume that this is a production level code.

```
 def get_customer_info(self, name):
        """ get customer info
        Args:
            name (str) : name of the customer
        """

        if not self.customers[name]:
            raise KeyError('I am sorry! Customer does not exist')

        return self.customers[name]
```

Comment: There really is no 'elegant' way to raise an error, what does it even mean to raise an error elegantly? What you have done is pretty much what is meant to be done.

Comment: It's not about *how you raise the error*, it's about *how you handle it*. That's where you need to focus on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would depend on the demands of the software.
Ideally the user should be informed that their input is invalid prior to submitting the form, greying out the submit button and prompting for a username to be entered.

If submitted, the error should be logged allowing statistics to be generated, if this is a very critical or unusual error then emails should be automatically generated and sent to relevant personnel.

The user should be redirected back to the input form *with the information they submitted previously still intact*, do not force the user to resubmit the whole form.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the class dict has not been redefined. Line 7,

```
    if not self.customers[name]:
```

will raise a KeyError if name does not appear in the dict. That means your code will never reach line 8.

```
    raise KeyError('I am sorry! Customer does not exist')
```

Solution: I would first catch the error. Then customize the error output.

```
    try:
        return self.customers[name]
    except KeyError:
        raise KeyError('I am sorry! Customer does not exist')
```

An alternative method that I prefer would be to write to stderr.

```
    from __future__ import print_function
    import sys
    ...
        def error(self, *objs):
            print("[ERROR]:",*objs,file=sys.stderr)

        def get_info(self,name):
            try:
                return self.customer[name]
            except KeyError:
                self.error("CUSTOMER NAME NOT FOUND: %s"%(name))
```

I prefer the alternative method because you probably don't want to handle exceptions in the calling code.

Comment: No, if the `key` doesn't appear in dict then it will raise an `KeyError`. This answer is not helpful, probably you should delete it.

Comment: Line 7 will raise an exception. Your code on line 8 will never be executed.